# How to compute $\pi_1(B)$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Compute $\pi_1(S^1 \vee S^1)$

My attempt :$\pi_1(S^1 \vee S^1,x)\cong\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$

[image]

[image]

[image]

**My  question**:  How  to   compute  $\pi_1(B)$(see  the given  figure)   ?

My attempt : This  can be shown  by the diagram [image]

from  the given diagram B  retract  to the circle

But  I want  mathematical proof

Comment: You're essentially trying to show that an arc deformation retracts onto a point because the circle remains unchanged throughout this transformation, so you can define an arc to be some portion of the circle (using the parametric equation) and "slide" every point on the arc to a point, which gives you a deformation retraction. I believe the explicit expression is not too hard to find.

Comment: can you find it ?@Kevin.S I'm not able to find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can show that $B$ and $S^1$ are homotopy equivalent, i.e. There is a map $f:B\to S^1$ and a map $g:S^1\to B$ such that $f\circ g\simeq Id_{S^1}$ and $g\circ f\simeq Id_B$.

$B$ can be expressed as $([-1,1],0)\lor (S^1,s_0)$. Consider $f:B\to S^1$ defined by $f(t,s_0)=s_0$ for all $t\in [-1,1]$ and $f(0,s)=s$ for all $s\in S^1$. And also $g:S^1\to B$ defined by $g(s)=(0,s)$for all $s\in S^1$.

Observe that
$$f(g(s))=f(0,s)=s,\ \forall s\in S^1$$
($f\circ g = Id_{S^1}$ and therefore $f\circ g \simeq Id_{S^1}$ ),
$$g(f(t,s_0))=g(s_0)=(0,s_0)$$
and
$$g(f(0,s))=g(s)=(0,s).$$
So we only need to prove that $g\circ f\simeq Id_B$. To do so consider the following homotopy:
$$H:B\times I\to B,\quad H((t,s_0),\lambda)=(\lambda t,s_0),\quad H((0,s),\lambda)=(0,s).$$

We can see that $H((t,s_0),0)=(0,s_0)$ and $H((0,s),0)=(0,s)$ so we have $H_0=g\circ f$. Also, $H((t,s_0),1)=(t,s_0)$ and $H((0,s),1)=(0,s)$, thus $H_1=Id_B$. Therefore we can conclude that $g\circ f\simeq Id_B$.

As homotopy equivalences induces a isomorphism between homotopy groups, we have $$\pi_1(B)\simeq \pi_1(S^1)=\mathbb{Z}.$$